# UserDefault value does not update in a list SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsuserdefaults

I have two views, embedded in TabView.
I am using userdefaults in a class called usersettings.

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var favList: [String] {
        willSet {
            print("willset")
        }
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(favList, forKey: "isAccountPrivate")
            print("didset")
        }
    }
    init() {
        self.favList = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "isAccountPrivate") as? [String] ?? ["Sepetiniz Boş"]
    }
}
```

In Button View, which acts like add/remove favorite. It successfully adds and remove from the UserDefaults. But when I add something it does not show on the other view (please see the next code after FavButton)

```
struct FavButton: View {
    
    @Binding var passedFood: String
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            if userSettings.favList.contains(passedFood) {
                userSettings.favList.remove(at: userSettings.favList.firstIndex(of: passedFood )!)
            } else {
                
                userSettings.favList.append(passedFood)
                
            }
            
        })  
        
    }
}
```

But it does not update my list in this other view unless I close and open my app. If I remove something from the list, it actually removes from the userdefault.

If I add a new word within this view, it works too.

**My only problem is when I add something from another view (FavButton) it does not show in this view (FavView).**

```
struct FavView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    @State private var newWord = ""

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                TextField("Ürün Ekleyin...", text: $newWord, onCommit: addNewWord)
                ForEach( self.userSettings.favList, id: \.self) { list in
                    Text(list)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                    
                }
                .onDelete(perform: self.deleteRow)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Sepetim")
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteRow(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
        
        self.userSettings.favList.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
    
    private func addNewWord() {
        let answer = newWord.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        self.userSettings.favList.append(answer)
        guard answer.count > 0 else {
            return
        }
        newWord = ""
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use same instance of `UserSettings` in all views where you want to have observed user settings, like

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
   static let global = UserSettings()
//... other code
}
```

and now

```
struct FavButton: View {
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings.global    // << here !!

// ... other code
}
```

and

```
struct FavView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings.global   // << here !!

// ... other code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach to follow the SwiftUI idiom is to use the `.environmentObject()` modifier.

When you declare your app:

```
struct AppScene: App {

  @StateObject private var userSettings = UserSettings() // Use state object to persist the object

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .environmentObject(userSettings) // Inject userSettings into the environment 
    }
  }
}
```

and then in you `ContentView` you can reach into your environment and get the object:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var userSettings: UserSettings
  var body: some View {
    Text("Number of items in favList: \(userSettings.favList.count)")
  }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it is really better, but EnvironmentObject works only in SwiftUI view hierarchy, so you cannot share it with UIKit views, other classes, and need to remember to reinject between different SwiftUI view hierarchies... so there are many pitfalls. Be aware.